# How can I authenticate JasperReports Server as part of link or bypass authentication

Tags: rest, jasperserver

I am using *JasperReports Server* web services to access a report through a link. For example:

http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/Statement.html?customer_id=NS10000?beginDate=2016-01-01?endDate=2016-02-26

This works, but I always have to enter the server username and password. Is there a way I can bypass the authentication or do it within the link without the username and password being visible in the url?

Answer (score 0):

You must send authentication request before requesting the report :

`GET http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest/login?j_username=user&j_password=p@ssw0rd`

You can found this and more in [the official documentation](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v56/login-service)